# Itemspacing in Maui felxlayout

Tags: xaml, layout, maui

My app contains a Flexlayout inside a scrollview. This flexlayout is used as a bindablelayout and contains some items. When there are enough items to fill the screen the vertical itemspacing is nicely done:

[image]

However, if the list gets smaller, and less items are visible, the vertical spacing becomes weird (I suspect the items want to fill out the whole available space, but I'm not sure of that):

[image]

I want the items to always have the same space between rows. Is this possible?

Xaml:

```
        <ScrollView Margin="10" Grid.Row="1" x:Name="UserActionScrollView">
            <FlexLayout x:Name="UserActionFlexLayout" BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding DisplayedUserActions}" JustifyContent="Start" Wrap="Wrap" Direction="Row">
                <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                       -- Datatemplate --
                    </DataTemplate>
                </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
            </FlexLayout>
        </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code, the main axis is horizontal direction with multiple lines. So you could set the alignment of cross axis(vertical direction) using **AlignContent**.

You could set like this:

```
<FlexLayout x:Name="UserActionFlexLayout" ... AlignContent="Start">
```

By the way, i think you could use CollectionView instead for this case. You could customize the layout you want. For example, you could use **ItemsLayout**  property:

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding DisplayedUserActions}">

        <!--set 3 columns, and itemspacing for each direction-->

        <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
            <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical"
                    Span="3" VerticalItemSpacing="20"  HorizontalItemSpacing="20"/>
        </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                ...
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

Also, you don't have to put it in a **ScrollView** as **CollectionView** can scroll itself.

For more info, you could refer to [FlexLayout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/layouts/flexlayout?view=net-maui-7.0#aligncontent) and [Specify CollectionView layout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/collectionview/layout?view=net-maui-7.0)

Hope it works for you.

Comment: Thanks! The Aligncontent worked for me. I failed to specify, that there don't have to be exactly 3 columns, it should depend on the size of the device. That's why I'm using a Flexlayout.